# boot2docker windows 10, unable to access container via browser

Tags: apache, docker, windows-10, boot2docker

I am trying to use docker on Windows 10 via boot2docker and VB.

- `boot2docker ssh`
- `boot2docker ip` => `192.168.59.103`
- `docker run -tip 80:80 tutum/apache-php bash`
- `ping 192.168.59.103 from host machine`

It is sounds working pretty good exepts :

- via the browser, when I go to `http://192.168.59.103` the page is not found

Do you have some idea about my issue ?

Thanks.

Edit : my logs

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
ecb75ba8f5f9        tutum/apache-php    "/run.sh"           20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   ecstatic_galileo
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker logs ec
==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==

==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==

==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Mon Aug 17 10:18:25.361931 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 17 10:18:25.363857 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You've told the container to run a bash shell, not a web server.

Try changing the run command to:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 tutum/apache-php
```

Then accessing the URL. The should run the default command for the container, which will presumably start apache. In your case you overrode the default command to be "bash", which won't start apache.

Comment: https://github.com/tutumcloud/apache-php/blob/master/Dockerfile: default command is run.sh. Of course... I should have spotted that immediately. +1

Comment: Can you add the output of running "docker logs" on the container to your question?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Double check you're using the right IP; it should be displayed by boot2docker ip. Other than that, it may be a VM issue, possibly because of running VonC's solution. It's probably worth checking if http://localhost works.

Comment: Ip is correct, and localhost not working. I don't know what is the problem with my config. :S

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling? I'm worried the networking has been broken in your VM. Just to confirm it's a VM/host networking issue, try running boot2docker ssh then curl http://localhost

Comment: Yes it's a network issue, curl request to localhost works fine, I see the HTML code. What is wrong ?